# hive on tez throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hive, apache-tez

I have deployed tez and configured hive to work on tez.

Simple query fails on reducer phase.

It throws this error:

Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1469020577348_0014)

---

### VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED

Map 1              SUCCEEDED      0          0        0        0       0       0

### Reducer 2             FAILED      1          0        0        1       4       0

### VERTICES: 01/02  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 12.15 s

Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1469020577348_0014_1_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1469020577348_0014_1_01_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1469020577348_0014_1_01_000000_0:java.lang.Exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskID: method (Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskType;I)V not found
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.initialize(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:267)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:69)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskID: method (Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskType;I)V not found

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because your hive has compiled with a different version of tez you are using.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14356